# Query on First 50,000 MAUs per month are free for both P1 and P2 Features

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

One of our customer would like to use Azure AD B2C.

They need confirmation about the calculation of the free tier of the first 50k MAU, whether it is based on per Azure AD B2C resource that they create or combine for all AD B2C that were created under 1 tenant?

Any guidance would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Billing considers all MAU from all Azure AD B2C tenants (resources). For more information please take a look to [Azure Active Directory External Identities pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/external-identities/).

Comment: Thank very much, Alfredo R.

Comment: @BalaMurugan I would love if you can approve the answer, somebody put it a -1 although its correct.